# Menu item is not highlighted after Request.redirect with parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I did not pass any parameters, the menu item is highlighted.However, when i try to pass parameters in Request.redirect, the corresponding menu item is not highlighted. What should I do to highlight it?

Comment: Hi, sorry, but to me this seems more like a riddle than a question... can you try to clarify?

Comment: Sorry about the unclear description. In my asp.net project, I need to redirect to another page using Request.redirect with parameters. However, after the redirection, the corresponding item/bar/tab in the top menu is not highlighted. How should i highlight it? Hopefully it is clear this time.

Comment: Is this `MVC` or `WebForms`?

Comment: There is no such thing as Request.redirect. Maybe you mean `Response.Redirect`? Even so, the question has not enough context. How are the menu items highlighted in general? Server side or client side? Please, read the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then come back and ask your question again.